# The encoding (CMap) specified by a font is missing. Error number: 537067605

Tags: adobe-pdf-library

Using the Datalogics.PDFL when I attempt to save some PDFs I get the following error:

The encoding (CMap) specified by a font is missing. Error number: 537067605

I can open and save other PDFs.

I tried installing all the referenced fonts I could discover but still the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This typically occurs when you fail to specify the path to the CMap directory upon initialization.  Our sample code demonstrates how to do this and if you run one of our samples you shouldn't encounter this issue as the samples are setup during initialization with the path to the CMap directory that's installed with the SDK.

If you check our [sample](https://github.com/datalogics/adobe-pdf-library-samples/blob/master/CPlusPlus/Sample_Source/_Common/InitializeLibrary.cpp#L199) code you can see a simple example of how this is done.

If you still have issues, please contact our Support (tech_support@datalogics.com) department so we can assist you more directly.